# Find commnad ID of VSIX command VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsix

In VS2017 I am writing my own VSIX command in C#. From C# code I wanted to call another VSIX command (Which is not mine, I known only tool tip on that button). How to find command Id for that button?

I tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1cb2c324-d8a7-4327-b63e-84d23a6b717b/vsix-enablevsiplogging-how-to-find-commandsmenus-guid-and-id-in-visual-studio2017?forum=vsarch)
but not helping

Even I tried this too, but not luck

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\" + DTE.Version + @"\General");
        key.SetValue("EnableVSIPLogging", 1);
    }
}
```

Get the command Id assoaciated with VSIX command (button).

Answer (score 1):

VS 2017 and newer no longer leverage the system registry, so attempting to set that registry key for VS 2017, VS 2019, etc will no longer work. These settings now resides in a privateregistry.bin, and while you can edit it direction as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/tools-for-managing-visual-studio-instances?view=vs-2019), or use the vsregedit.exe utility, but I don't really recommend either. Editing the privateregistry.bin is tricky, and vsregedit.exe isn't documented.

Nowadays, I recommend installing Mads [Extensibility Essentials package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensibilityEssentials2019). This includes a package that will add a "Enable VSIP Logging" menu command under the "View" menu (you'll need restart VS for the change to take effect).

Once installed, you just drop down the menu with the command you are interested in, then while holding the CTRL+SHIFT keys, click the menu item you want the details on. This will display a "VSDebug Message" dialog with the Guid and CmdID that uniquely identify the menu command you clicked on.  Please note, this only works for menu commands and toolbar buttons created via the VSSDK's VSCT compiler. Some toolwindows may have custom WPF based menus or toolbars, that are not implemented using the VS extensibility APIs and resources. In those scenarios, you cannot use VS extensibility api's to invoke them.

Sincerely,

Comment: The command above runs inside Visual Studio by Visual Commander and thus changes the private registry.

Comment: I have VS2019, changing the registry under "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_5b74d3a2\General" worked for me

Comment: I tried the Extensibility Essentials package for the same goal (get VSIPLogging working) and it didn't work for me.